# How to get installed informix version from windows registry

Tags: windows, registry, informix

Since I dont have access to all the of the released Informix versions (or) editions in combination so I am looking for a way to look into the windows registry that gets me the installed version of Informix DB server.

P.S.- It can be a simple (key,value) access or it can be a logic of enumerating multiple keys to get it. All i need is a definite way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the reference to others.

Informix makes its registry entries under HKLM\Software\Informix.

Under that hive, there are entries for other components one of which is the DBMS.

So if you look inside the hive of HKLM\software\Informix\DBMS you can see the installed version of DBMS say 11.9 and under which there is current version Value is there which list the correct version installed.